# SmartTV: Object has no method 'sfList'

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

In one on my scenes I have

```
<div id="itemsList"></div>
```

then I add list to it like this:

```
$('#itemsList').sfList({
    data : [ 'AAA', 'BBBB', 'CCC']
});
```

But in the console appears:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'sfList'
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your index.html. Is there any JS link to loader.js or sf.min.js?
Those two javascript contains the sf objects including the sfList function.

If you develop the application using "Javascript project" it's not included automatically but if you choose "Basic Project" the loader.js should be there.